# Enable WIFI and/or mobile data from Android app (C++Builder XE6)

Tags: android, mobile, wifi, c++builder

I've been looking for a way to enable WIFI and/or mobile data from my Android-app (C++Builder XE6) but thus far I haven't found a way to do so. Browsed header-files, samples and internet but no luck so far. The whole Android part is pretty new to me, C++Builder is not.

Am I missing a component or sample here or should it be that easy it's listed nowhere? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about C++Builder but I do know Android doesn't allow enabling wifi or mobile programatically - this must be done explicitly by the user.

You can do this in your code by checking to see if any network is enabled and, if not, taking them to the relevant settings page.

There is a subtle exception to my first statement though - if both wifi and mobile are enabled then the wifi connection will be the default used. If you want to switch to mobile it *is* possible to switch off (but not disable) the wifi network connection programmatically.

Comment: Thank you! But there are apps which can enable/disable Wifi. For example https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wifi.timer, so how is this done?

Comment: @user3585140 : Perhaps there is a slightly loose interpretation of enable/disable, switch on/off and connect/disconnect. From my experience the user must have enabled the network manually themselves. After that you can use `WifiManager` to disconnect and reconnect (switch on/off). See the `WifiManager` docs... https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

Comment: That's pretty much how that mentioned app acts, (although this could be a startup bug too) either the app has to be started or wifi has to be enabled (and disabled) before the app does what it is supposed to do. But, it IS able to enable and disable wifi.